# Trouble with dynamic refreshing div

Tags: php, jquery, html, refresh

I make div which refresh when file is updated. But it continuously refresh (fade out and fade in every second).
I't source test2.php

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js>
    </script>                          
    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#loaddiv').load('check.chat.php');
     });


    var auto_refresh = setInterval( function() {
    $.ajax(
        {
        type: 'POST',
        data:"id=100",
        url: "check.chat.php",
        success: function(result) 
        {
            if($("#loaddiv").html() != result)
            {
                $("#loaddiv").fadeOut("fast")
                $("#loaddiv").html(result);
                $("#loaddiv").fadeIn("slow");
           }
        }
    });
    }, 1000);
    </script>

    <div id="loaddiv"></div>
```

And file on site: ********

Who knows what's the problem?

Comment: because you using `setInterval()`, it do things with interval you provided, you need to refresh your page in success callback only

Comment: The problem lay within you comparison `if($("#loaddiv").html() != result)`. Not sure why at the moment, but that if statement always validates to true, and therefor your content flickers. Have to tried to log both the result of the Ajax-call and the old HTML, so that you can see what they really look like. My guess is that there is something fishy going on there.

Comment: Andrzej, use Firebug (addon) to debug ajax and do just about anything else JS related in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part:

```
$("#loaddiv").fadeOut("fast")
$("#loaddiv").html(result);
$("#loaddiv").fadeIn("slow");
```

Should be:

```
$("#loaddiv").fadeOut("fast", function(){
        $("#loaddiv").html(result);
        $("#loaddiv").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

In your case, both fades are called at the same time, making an animation queue, causing it to go from one phase to another in about the same time the interval triggers again.

---

UPDATE

To see logs, do this: `console.log("html: ", $("#loaddiv").html(), "result: ", result);`

Comment: I tried it but still fade out and fade in every second although it's same text. Maybe it's problem which check.chat which generate text from mysql?

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't say anything about that since there's no code... What does the console.log say for both the load div and the ajax result?

Comment: Right above the if clause. And you'll see the log using Dev Tools in Chrome (CTRL+Shift+I) and in Firebug in Firefox (there are also equivalents in Opera, etc).

Comment: html:  


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


sdfsdf;2012-09-25;xxxxxxxx; result:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="pl-PL">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

sdfsdf;2012-09-25;xxxxxxxx;

Comment: that's it then... the php file should only output `sdfsdf;2012-09-25;xxxxxxxx` not the whole HTML structure.